# express - Limit a request to one at a time

Tags: node.js, express, rate-limiting

I'm using [`express`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express) to build a API that should be used internally. One of the request trigger an heavy process on the server and should return a CSV out of that. This process might take more than 10 minutes.

To not overloading the server I want to restrict the call of this API and make it so that, since the process isn't terminated, we can't request the same URL again.

For this I tried to use [`express-rate-limit`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-rate-limit) with the following configuration:

```
new RateLimit({
    windowMs: 30 * 60 * 1000, // 30 minutes
    max: 1,
    delayMs: 0, // disabled
    message: 'Their is already a running execution of the request. You must wait for it to be finished before starting a new one.',
    handler: function handler(req, res) {
        logger.log('max request achieved');
        logger.log(res);
    },
});
```

But it seems that the 'max request' is reached every time after exactly 2 mins even if I start only once. I suspect the browser to retry the request after 2 min if doesn't get any answer, is it possible?

I would like that this request doesn't have any `retry-strategy` and that the only way the `max request` is reached is by manually asking the server to execute this request 2 times in a row.

Thank's.

---

### Edit

Here is my full code:

```
const app = express();
const port = process.env.API_PORT || 3000;

app.enable('trust proxy');

function haltOnTimedout(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.timedout) { next(); }
}

app.use(timeout(30 * 60 * 1000)); // 30min
app.use(haltOnTimedout);

app.listen(port, () => {
    logger.log(`Express server listening on port ${port}`);
});

// BILLING
const billingApiLimiter = new RateLimit({
    windowMs: 30 * 60 * 1000, // 30 minutes
    max: 1,
    delayMs: 0, // disabled
    message: 'Their is already a running execution of the request. You must wait for it to be finished before starting a new one.',
    handler: function handler(req, res) {
        logger.log('max request achieved');
    },
});

app.use('/billing', billingApiLimiter);
app.use('/billing', BillingController);
```

And the code of my `route`:

```
router.get('/billableElements', async (request, response) => {
    logger.log('Route [billableElements] called');
    const { startDate } = request.query;
    const { endDate } = request.query;
    try {
        const configDoc = await metadataBucket.getAsync(process.env.BILLING_CONFIG_FILE || 'CONFIG_BILLING');
        const billableElements = await getBillableElements(startDate, endDate, configDoc.value);
        const csv = await produceCSV(billableElements);
        logger.log('csv produced');
        response.status(200).send(`${csv}`);
    } catch (err) {
        logger.error('An error occured while getting billable elements.', err);
        response.status(500).send('An internal error occured.');
    }
});
```

Comment: This feels like a bad design, to me. Rate limiting is normally done more for compliance with a pricing plan or to prevent DOS attacks, not to account for a long running process.  Have you considered employing a job queue or similar to ensure your back end is only given one job at a time instead of using a rate limiting tool?

Comment: @Paul is right, a queue with a worker would probably tackle this better. If you did want to do this, then I'd probably recommend just putting a bit of code in the desired endpoint which checks if the process is running already and returns an error if it is. IE: you could store the fact that a process is running in a db (or redis), check that first, and release the "lock" when the process is done. This is not really a super reliant way to do it, but if the whole process is fairly simple it might achieve what you're after.

Comment: Thanks @Paul and @Elliot! Setting a lock was my first idea and I was terminating the request in case the lock wasn't released but it was always receiving a second call after 2 mins and then returning an error to the client. I think this is due to some 'retry strategy' but I'm really not an expert. If I use a `JobQueue` this will avoid overloading the server but it still the same issue where my request is executed every 2 mins. I tried to set a timeout with `connect-timeout` but maybe I'm doing it wrong because it doesn't change anything.

Comment: I added some extra code inside the question.

Comment: How long does it take you to generate that csv?

Comment: Also, how often does that config file change? That doesn't seem to be the kind of thing you need to fetch on every request. Most folks load config on app startup and just reference the in memory version thereafter.

Comment: I found the reason why the request was fired every 2 mins thank's to this github ticket: https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/2512. I will mark it as an answer but your advice are still good to take into account. I will move the configuration file to the start of the app and I will consider using a JobQueue instead of rate-limiting my request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer thank's to this GitHub issue: https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/2512.

TLDR: I added `request.connection.setTimeout(1000 * 60 * 30);` to avoid firing the request every 2 minutes.

But considering the code I wrote inside my question, @Paul's advices are still good to be taken into account.