# Set request time limit in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to reproduce a couple of errors that happen when requests fail on the server. I want to temporarily set a time limit on all requests to keep them from being able to execute successfully. Is something like this possible? I am using Node and Express.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_settimeout_timeout_callback

Comment: It's help for you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50528166/express-limit-a-request-to-one-at-a-time

Comment: This is useful for one request, but i have potentially dozens of methods that i need to check. is there a way to set a limit for ALL requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you initialize express using the http server, you can use [server.timeout](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/http.html#http_server_timeout).
It sets the timeout for *all incoming requests*.

```
const app = express()
const http = require('http')
const server = http.createServer(app)
server.timeout = 10; //milliseconds
server.listen(3000)
```

There is also a `server.setTimeout` function that receives a callback. The callback gets executed for every request that times out.

```
server.setTimeout(20, () => {
  console.log('request timed out');
})
```